# Convert an array of json objects in to another json object

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have an array of json objects as shown below.

```
[
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "issue",
        "eventType": "creation"
      },
      "id": 39,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "issue",
        "eventType": "predeletion"
      },
      "id": 40,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "issue",
        "eventType": "deletion"
      },
      "id": 41,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "issue",
        "eventType": "update"
      },
      "id": 42,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "recquirement",
        "eventType": "new"
      },
      "id": 43,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "jira",
        "domainObject": "recquirement",
        "eventType": "old"
      },
      "id": 44,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "bitbucket",
        "domainObject": "branch",
        "eventType": "creation"
      },
      "id": 45,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "bitbucket",
        "domainObject": "branch",
        "eventType": "deletion"
      },
      "id": 46,
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "wrappedItem": {
        "systemName": "bitbucket",
        "domainObject": "pull-request",
        "eventType": "creation"
      },
      "id": 47,
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
```

If you closely observe the data above, you can see that the data can be grouped based on the `systemName`, followed by the `domainObject`, followed by `eventType`.

I want to display the data into a tree like fashion. For this, I have decided to use [angular-ui-tree](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example) third party library. It expects the json object to be in a certain way. (Please go to that link to see the structure of the json object it needs).

I have a requirement where I have to convert my data into a structure needed by the `angular-ui-tree` so that I can display my data as a tree.

Eventually, I am expecting the json object to look like :

```
[
  {
    "systemName": "jira",
    "domains": [
      {
        "domainObject": "issue",
        "eventTypes": [
          {
            "eventType": "creation",
            "id": 39,
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "eventType": "pre-deletion",
            "id": 40,
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "eventType": "deletion",
            "id": 41,
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "eventType": "issue",
            "id": 42,
            "enabled": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "domainObject": "requirement",
        "eventTypes": [
          {
            "eventType": "new",
            "id": 43,
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "eventType": "old",
            "id": 44,
            "enabled": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "systemName": "bitbucket",
    "domains": [
      {
        "domainObject": "branch",
        "eventTypes": [
          {
            "eventType": "creation",
            "id": 45,
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "eventType": "deletion",
            "id": 46,
            "enabled": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "domainObject": "pull-request",
        "eventTypes": [
          {
            "eventType": "creation",
            "id": 47,
            "enabled": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see this data is grouped by `systemName`, followed by `domainObject` and followed by `eventType`.
Can someone help me in converting my data in the structure shown above.

Comment: What have you tried? you need to demonstrate effort in trying to solve the problem yourself

Comment: There is no "json object". JSON is a notation based on ECMAScript object literal syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` to hash the object and their subobject, then use `Object.keys` with `map` to transform those hash object into an array like this:

```
function group(arr) {
    // PHASE 1: wrap the object and the sub-objects into hash objects (group them)
    var hash = arr.reduce(function(h, o) {                                // for each object o in the array arr
        var sn = o.wrappedItem.systemName;                                // get the systemName
        var dob = o.wrappedItem.domainObject;                             // get the domainObject
        var ev = {eventType: o.wrappedItem.eventType, id: o.id, enabled: o.enabled}; // create an eventType object 
        if(h[sn]) {                                                       // if the systemName sn is already hashed
            if(h[sn].domainHash[dob])                                     // if the domain object dob is already hashed
                h[sn].domainHash[dob].eventTypes.push(ev);                // then push the eventType ev into its eventTypes array
            else                                                          // if not (the domain object is not hashed yet) then create a new domain object that have the eventType ev as the only item in its eventTypes array
                h[sn].domainHash[dob] = {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]};
        }
        else {                                                            // if not (the systemName sn is not hashed yet)
            h[sn] = {systemName: sn, domainHash: {}};                     // create a new systemName object with its domainHash object initialized with the domain object dob which is also initalized with the eventType ev
            h[sn].domainHash[dob] = {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]};
        }

        return h;
    }, {});

    // PHASE 2: unwrap the hash objects
    return Object.keys(hash).map(function(o) {                            // unwrap hash
        var domains = Object.keys(hash[o].domainHash).map(function(d) {   // unwrap domainHash
            return hash[o].domainHash[d];
        });
        delete hash[o].domainHash;                                        // remove the property domainHash
        hash[o].domains = domains;                                        // replace it with the property domains
        return hash[o];
    });
}
```

**Example:**

```js
var array = [{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"issue","eventType":"creation"},"id":39,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"issue","eventType":"predeletion"},"id":40,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"issue","eventType":"deletion"},"id":41,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"issue","eventType":"update"},"id":42,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"recquirement","eventType":"new"},"id":43,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"jira","domainObject":"recquirement","eventType":"old"},"id":44,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"bitbucket","domainObject":"branch","eventType":"creation"},"id":45,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"bitbucket","domainObject":"branch","eventType":"deletion"},"id":46,"enabled":true},{"wrappedItem":{"systemName":"bitbucket","domainObject":"pull-request","eventType":"creation"},"id":47,"enabled":true}];

function group(arr) {
    var hash = arr.reduce(function(h, o) {
        var sn = o.wrappedItem.systemName;
        var dob = o.wrappedItem.domainObject;
        var ev = {eventType: o.wrappedItem.eventType, id: o.id, enabled: o.enabled};
        if(h[sn]) {
            if(h[sn].domainHash[dob])
                h[sn].domainHash[dob].eventTypes.push(ev);
            else
                h[sn].domainHash[dob] = {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]};
        }
        else {
            h[sn] = {systemName: sn, domainHash: {}};
            h[sn].domainHash[dob] = {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]};
        }

        return h;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(hash).map(function(o) {
        var domains = Object.keys(hash[o].domainHash).map(function(d) {
            return hash[o].domainHash[d];
        });
        delete hash[o].domainHash;
        hash[o].domains = domains;
        return hash[o];
    });
}


console.log(group(array));
```

**Explanation:**

After phase 1, we get an object like this:

```
{
  "jira": {
    systemName: "jira",
    domainHash: {
      "issue": {
        domainObject: "issue",
        eventTypes: [...]
      },
      "other domain object": {
        domainObject: "other domain object",
        eventTypes: [...]
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  "other system name": {
    systemName: "other system name",
    domainHash: {
      "something": {
        domainObject: "something",
        eventTypes: [...]
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Which is not the output you want, the hashing makes it easier to group items, but the output will be an object. So to get the desired result (an array), you'll have too map the sub-object of the hash object into an array.

```
var result = {
  hash["jira"],
  hash["other system name"],
  ...
];
```

And not just the systemName objects that need mapping, the domainObject objects need to be mapped too (for each systemName object):

```
var domains = [
  domainHash["issue"],
  domainHash["other domain object"],
  ...
];
```

Comment: When i use your snippet, I get an error on line `h[sn] = {systemName: sn, domainHash: {[dob]: {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]}}};`. The error is `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ":", invalid 
  AssignmentOperator
 - Syntax error on token "{", } expected after this 
  token
 - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token`

Comment: @RITZXAVI I've just test it the snippet and it's working! Are you testing it here or are you copying it somewhere else?

Comment: No i am not testing it here. I using your code in my angularjs controller on eclipse. I get the error there. And also when I am trying to build my project, I use JSlint. There I am getting few more errors. I will post those errors in the comments below.

Comment: `132,59: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 132 and instead saw '['.
132,60: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 132 and instead saw 'dob'.
132,63: Missing semicolon.
132,63: Expected an identifier and instead saw ']'.
132,63: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
132,64: Missing semicolon.
132,64: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 131 and instead saw ':'.
132,81: Label 'domainObject' on dob statement.
132,86: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
132,96: Missing semicolon.`

Comment: `132,96: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 132 and instead saw ':'.
132,101: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
132,102: Missing semicolon.
132,103: Expected ')' and instead saw '}'.
132,104: Missing semicolon.
135,17: Expected ']' to match '[' from line 3 and instead saw 'return'.
135,24: Expected ')' and instead saw 'h'.
136,18: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
148,9: Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'.`

Comment: Line 132 in my angularjs controller javascript file is `h[sn] = {systemName: sn, domainHash: {[dob]: {domainObject: dob, eventTypes: [ev]}}};`.  Any idea why I am getting these errors?

Comment: @RITZXAVI I guess angular doen't allow keys from variables while constructing the object. I separated that line into two lines, please take a look, I've updated my answer!

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail about phase 2 and why we have to do it ? From what I have understood, Haven't we already transformed the data in the format we need in phase 1 itself ?

Comment: @RITZXAVI I added an explanation, I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested hash table and group the items with the given keys.

Basically this proposal works for various length of grouping properties. In this case it groups by

> ```
> groups = {
>     'wrappedItem.systemName': 'domains',
>     'wrappedItem.domainObject': 'eventTypes'
> }
> ```

Then it need a function for building the final object

> ```
> {
>     eventType: "creation",
>     id: 39,
>     enabled: true
> }
> ```

at the end of the nested grouping with

> ```
> fn = function (o) {
>     return { eventType: o.wrappedItem.eventType, id: o.id, enabled: o.enabled };
> }
> ```

The function `getGroupedData`, expects a data array, a grouping object and callback for generating an inner item.

The key functionaliy is an object, which holds an array for each level of groups.

On start, the hash table has one property and the reference to the result array

> ```
> {
>     _: result
> }
> ```

In the first loop of the data array and by iterating all groups, it gets a new level for each group.

First it gets the value of the first group property, which is `'jira'`. It  is taken for a check if the property exist in the hash table. `'jira'` does actually not exist and a new object is generated with the same pattern as the original hash table.

> ```
> {
>     _: result
>     jira: { _: [] }
> }
> ```

And another object is generated for the result set

> ```
> {
>     systemName: "jira",
>     domains": []
> }
> ```

and added to the result

> ```
> {
>     _: [
>         {
>             systemName: "jira",
>             domains: [] // <---+
>         }               //     | domains and jira._ 
>     ],                  //     | share the same 
>     jira: {             //     | reference to the array
>         _: []           // <---+
>     }
> }
> ```

Why do I need two different reference to the result array?

Because you need a special data structure for the result. It is array oriented, but the access is done via indices. The other structure has a direct access by a property, which is easier to access, without more methods.

For the next group, the object of `jira` is returned and another check is performed, if in the actual object is a property with the name `'issue'`. This is obviously in the first loop not the case and added. The actual object looks like

> ```
> {
>     _: [
>         {
>             domainObject: "issue",
>             eventTypes: []
>         }
>     ],
>     issue: {
>         _: []
>     }
> }
> ```

And `_[0].eventTypes` and `issue._` shares again the same reference to an array.

Now at the end of the first loop of the data, the hash object looks like that

> ```
> {                                                  //   + same objects
>     _: [                                           //               -+ result set
>         {                                          //                |
>             systemName: "jira",                    //                |
>             domains: [                             //                |
>                 {                                  //         +      |
>                     domainObject: "issue",         //         +      |
>                     eventTypes: [                  //         +      |
>                         {                          //    +    +      |
>                             eventType: "creation", //    +    +      |
>                             id: 39,                //    +    +      |
>                             enabled: true          //    +    +      |
>                         }                          //    +    +      |
>                     ]                              //         +      |
>                 }                                  //         +      |
>             ]                                      //                |
>         }                                          //               -+
>     ],                                             //
>     jira: {                                        //
>         _: [                                       //
>             {                                      //         +
>                 domainObject: "issue",             //         +
>                 eventTypes: [                      //         +
>                     {                              //    +    +
>                         eventType: "creation",     //    +    +
>                         id: 39,                    //    +    +
>                         enabled: true              //    +    +
>                     }                              //    +    +
>                 ]                                  //         +
>             }                                      //         +
>         ],                                         //
>         issue: {                                   //
>             _: [                                   //
>                 {                                  //    +
>                     eventType: "creation",         //    +
>                     id: 39,                        //    +
>                     enabled: true                  //    +
>                 }                                  //    +
>             ]                                      //
>         }                                          //
>     }                                              //
> }                                                  //
> ```

The data array is looped to the end an all groupes are now in the object and all grouped arrays have been created. Then only the result set is returned.

```js
function getGroupedData(data, groups, fn) {
    var keys = Object.keys(groups),
        result = [];

    data.forEach(function (a) {
        keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            var temp,
                value = k.split('.').reduce(function (r, l) {
                    return (r || {})[l];
                }, a);
            if (!r[value]) {
                r[value] = { _: [] };
                temp = {};
                temp[k.split('.').pop()] = value;
                temp[groups[k]] = r[value]._;
                r._.push(temp);
            }
            return r[value];
        }, this)._.push(fn(a));
    }, { _: result });
    return result;
}


var data = [{ wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "issue", eventType: "creation" }, "id": 39, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "issue", eventType: "predeletion" }, "id": 40, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "issue", eventType: "deletion" }, "id": 41, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "issue", eventType: "update" }, "id": 42, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "recquirement", eventType: "new" }, "id": 43, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "jira", domainObject: "recquirement", eventType: "old" }, "id": 44, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "bitbucket", domainObject: "branch", eventType: "creation" }, "id": 45, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "bitbucket", domainObject: "branch", eventType: "deletion" }, "id": 46, enabled: true }, { wrappedItem: { systemName: "bitbucket", domainObject: "pull-request", eventType: "creation" }, "id": 47, enabled: true }],
    groups = { 'wrappedItem.systemName': 'domains', 'wrappedItem.domainObject': 'eventTypes' },
    fn = function (o) {
        return { eventType: o.wrappedItem.eventType, id: o.id, enabled: o.enabled };
    };

console.log(getGroupedData(data, groups, fn));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation of what your code is doing(just like the other answer by Ibrahim Mahrir) ? It would greatly help me to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much I have tried your solution and it works well. I wanted to mark this answer as the correct answer but I would be going with @Ibrahim Mahrir's answer and mark it as the correct answer as i find it trivial. But needless to say, your answer also works very well. I wish I could mark both yours and Ibrahim's answer as the correct one.

Comment: the other answer is hard coded. with my answer, you could easily add some more properties for grouping. anyway, it's ok, you are welcome.